# Toggle on/off basic auth in spring

Tags: java, spring, security, tomcat, basic-authentication

I am working on a spring webapp that has basic auth (backed by dao) built into it using Spring Security. I am looking to a way to toggle on/off the basic auth programatically, may be via a admin level rest call ? or may be via a file on disk written at runtime.

I tried solving it with spring profiles, but couldnt figure out a way to switch profile at run time - without restarting the application.

Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: Why would you wan't to turn off security? Security shouldn't be a feature you can toggle on or off. It must always be there to protect your sensitive data.

Comment: This is for QA/Prod purposes and add more flexibility to the system. Though this feature will/is supposed to be very rarely used only by admins.